# Embed HTML in RMarkdown Table

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to embed a data frame in an RMarkdown document where one column is a character vector of HTML links:

- row 1: `<a href="http://path/to/long/url/result1.html" target=_blank">link</a>`
- row 2: `<a href="http://path/to/long/url/result2.html" target=_blank">link</a>`
- etc.

I'd like this column to be printed as is (i.e. without HTML escaping), so that the links work in the output document. Is there a way to do this?

My output document type is 'html_notebook', and I would like to the data frame to be displayed as a paged table (function `rmarkdown:::print.paged_df`).